# Android Webview cannot load CSS and show blockquote font color effect

Tags: android, html, css

I have got the following html to be loaded on CSS through android webview . When it comes to the execution. there has no obseravle changes to the font color changes onto my wordings tagged by blockquote

the below is my html code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///android_asset/style.css" />
    </head>
        <blockquote>拜年根本係學溝通同交際#hehe#</blockquote>
        <br/><br/>唔明點解去完親戚屋企拜年 過幾日親戚要黎返我屋企再拜過年 [banghead]
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

blockquote{
color:#d4d3d3
  }
```

Actual android code

```
viewHolder.txContent = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.replycontent);
        WebSettings settings = viewHolder.txContent.getSettings();
        settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

        settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        viewHolder.txContent.setFocusable(false);
        viewHolder.txContent.setClickable(true);
        viewHolder.txContent.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFFFFF"));




String htmlPreffix = "<html><head><title>Example</title><link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"file:///android_asset/style.css\" /></head>";
            String htmlSuffixString = "</body></html>";

            System.out.println("htmlParsed");
            System.out.println(htmlPreffix + htmlParsed + htmlSuffixString);
            viewHolder.txContent.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlParsed, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the opening `<body>` tag.